# Dark (rotting?) spots on my aquarium plants?

Tags: aquatic-plants

I am def a noobie at all of this so apologies.

I'm getting dark (rotting?) spots on my plant.

I actually had some more earlier but I trimmed them as that's what I'm familiar with in the non-aquarium plant world.

The plant is in a sand base. I have plant tabs in the sand.

The lights are on 12+ hours during the day.

I haven't tested anything with my water yet.

Thanks for any input!

[image]

[image: Aquarium]